# how to publish node.js project in Cute-Ftp tools

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc-4

how to publish on node.js project in cuteftp?
node.js project publish is possible for cuteftp tools or not?

i am trying to node.js project publish or deploy in Cute-ftp tool currently this project is parallerly created in one solution in visual studio , my another project in mvc4 means eg p1 is mvc4 project and p2 id node.js project

Answer (score 0):

Try to new project , template , JavaScript ,node.js then select Blank azure node.js web application...